# Required FILEINFO PHP Extension, JSON PHP Extension, PDO PHP Extension, MBSTRING PHP Extension

Tags: php, json, pdo, fileinfo, mbstring

I installed a PHP Script on my domain, after testing it, I think the next one is better then this script. so that instead of uninstall method, i select the script folders from my `root/home` directory and deleted them. By mistake, I also delete some file or folder.

Now I want to install another script and it shows that these required PHP extensions are missing:

1. FILEINFO PHP Extension
2. JSON PHP Extension
3. PDO PHP Extension
4. MBSTRING PHP Extension

I search for solution of this problem and ending on SSH Access commands.. When i make a key of SSH Access and install putty on my machine. I came to know about the SSH policy of my hosting company. To get the SSH access, i request them about it and then they allow me. This is totally crash my nerves..

Can anybody tell me about the solution with in my circumstances? 
I have a Biz Hosting Plan in Qhoster.com on shared hosting server.

Comment: Did you take care of the initial installation process or was it part of the plan default image?  Just redo what you did the first time, or ask the hoster to do it.  Another solution could be to reinstall on another computer the same versions and copy the missing files over.

Comment: Problem is, i can't redo. Because files are deleted permanently and i have only Cpanel access.

Comment: How was the original system built?

Comment: Original system is Linux base server.. I don't know which file have the path of these extensions... Can you please teach me the extension installation methods through Cpanel or any place where i find the missing file.

I am using the PHP7. 2.7

  when i changed it to any version. It did not changed. (i am checking through phpinfo() method)